# WordPress adding shortcodes in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanna add a shortcode in the `functions.php` from WordPress, so I can use my function in my site.

The problem is, obviously the `shortcodes.php` is included **after** the `functions.php`, so it gives me an error:

> Call to undefined function `add_shortcode`

How can I add shortcodes in my `functions.php`?

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you referring to functions.php inside your theme's folder? Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: I am refering to the functions.php inside my wp-includes. Or is there any other way to include PHP on just ONE page? I don't know any better way. Thanks!

Comment: Do not add/change anything in `wp-includes` directory, that is core WP stuff and shouldnt be messed with unless you know exactly what you are doing.  you should add this to the `functions.php` in your active theme. if you are using a child theme, you can add a `functions.php` to that with just your shortcode in it

Comment: Thanks celeriko -> i have solved this now by simply creating a new plugin with my shortcode functions in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you do not want to alter your theme's `functions.php` file (for obvious reasons) you have two options

1. create a child theme and make a `functions.php` file with your shortcode in there.  Wordpress will recognize this file and automatically include it for you and as long as there is no naming conflicts with other functions in your parent theme's `functions.php`
2. create a new file, `custom_shortcodes.php` or something, with your custom shortcode in it and add it to your theme.  then in your theme's `functions.php`, at the very end, add the line

   `include 'custom_shortcodes.php';`

this will allow you to edit your custom shortcodes without having to alter the themes `functions.php`.  just know if you update your theme, you will have to add the above line back in to `functions.php`.  Personally, i always use a child theme and then end up using the first method but either is acceptable.

a last option, and what solved @xatenev problem, is to create a plugin and add all of your shortcodes to the plugin.  This makes your custom code 'portable' and allows you to use it on any theme you have installed without going into the theme folder and adding/changing files.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this by creating a new plugin now, which contains all shortcode functions and shortcodes. Thanks!

Comment: good solution! going to update my answer for anyone in the future

Answer (score 0):

reference from your functions.php to your shortcodes.php

So your functions.php could start like

```
<?php

// define the path   
$shortcodes_path = get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes';

// ** Get the shortcodes.php **
require_once $shortcodes_path . '/shortcodes.php';
```

This code will now on start load a file called "shortcodes.php" stored in a folder "shortcodes".

The line after define the path sets a shortcut the your themes folder and right there into a subfolder called "shortcodes".
The line direct after Get the shortcodes.php loads a file called "shortcodes.php" stored in that folder "shortcodes". So you could put all your css, js and so on cleaned up in a folder, using the $shortcodes_path to load the ressource.

Now you need to place the shortcodes file in this folder with the right name example could be

```
<?php
/* show content on mobilephones only */
    function showm( $atts, $content = null ) { 
        $content = wpautop(trim($content));
        return '<div class="visible-xs">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';  
    }  
    add_shortcode("show-m", "showm");
```

save and shoot. IF you're using bootstrap this shortcode will wrap your content into a div which will only be displayed on mobile devices.

two things:
1. As this is php it doesn't need a closing php tag, but if you're a cleancode-lover you'll do it anyway.
2. allways use "do_shortcode($content)" as this will allow the user to use a shortcode wrapped in a shortcode. FE: If you have the above shortcode for mobile devices and a shortcode for icons the user could use the icon shortcode to be displayed on mobile only.

SO MUCH WOW =) All the best
Fab

Comment: Thanks - anyways I solved this by creating a new plugin in which I store all my functions who need a shortcode. I didn't know that the "functions.php" all tutorials speak from, is the theme - functions.php instead of the functions.php in wp-includes/. Thanks anyways!